# Dropdownmenu in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.0

I know there are thousands of answers about creating a dropdown menu in ASP.Net but I haven´t found anyone which is made up for Core 1.0. It´s pretty new and I hope anyone of you can help me with my question. 
How to create a big dropdownmenu in Core 1.0. I tried it with this code:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li> <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Product</a></li>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a>Menu under Product</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
```

But then VS2015 says: The element ul can´t be created under another Element ul.

So i can´t hide and display it if u put your coursor over the Product Site. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Best Regards

CDRohling.

Comment: ASP.NET Core has nothing to do with it. You're dealing with HTML, CSS, and JS and that's not different. The only thing ASP.NET Core specific here is the asp-* attributes but that's not related to your actual problem. Looks like you're using Bootstrap for layout. Have you tried checking [their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)?

Comment: Yea you are right I´m using there layout. Good idea for checking there documentation. Thank you for this information. This helped me a much. I´m sorry for asking this dump question.

Comment: You could try considering using an alternative menu like bootstrap, kendo, or some other component, which will give you more documentation on the setup and be possibly easier to implement.  In addition, those aren't errors, but warnings right?  There's no reason a UL can't be in a UL; you'll get no runtime exception.  It's just highlighting it as a warning.

Comment: Yea, you are right there are just warnings and no errors. Thank you for your help!
I´ll try kendo then.

Comment: In general and for Bootstrap, you're actually going to want your Product `li` to wrap around the `.dropdown-menu` `ul`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. That helped me a much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I achived my goal with the documentation of Boostrap as mentioned above. In the end I added this Code to solve my Problem:

```
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Cloud">Cloud</a></li>                           
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Hopefully someone will need this some day.

Best Regards, CD Rohling